# How to get all communities a user is associated with?

Tags: support, api, users

Is there a way to get all Stack Exchange communities in which a user is active? I mean the list of communities that are displayed on a [user's network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what the [associated users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=21429130&filter=default&run=true) operation does:

[image]

It needs the network account ID of a user, which can be found in the [URL of a network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) or you can retrieve it via an API call to [users by IDs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) - the field `account_id` is in the default filter:

[image]